# Bridge tool creating abomination instead of connected edges

Tags: mesh, faces

Increasing number of cuts works horribly wrong. I was expecting somewhat a connected pipe or something. Is this a bug?

[image: gif]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, make sure that your object has scaling applied in **Object Mode** (Ctrl+A).

Then, use **"Smoothness"** to control the connection between loops.

[image]

Comment: Oh my god you're right! Thank you kind sir!